# How to create a child route in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I Have a project with with admin page(See the file structure below). I need to create a child route called '*createuser*' to admin page *(localhost:4200/admin/createuser)*. I tried few methods but it shows an error(Cannot find primary outlet to load 'CreateComponent'). So, I added *router-outlet* to my admin component html. Now, the routing code works but the html from admin page is showing in the '*createuser*' page. How to avoid that? Or Have I missed something?

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'admin',
    templateUrl: 'admin.component.html'
})

export class AdminComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

**admin.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="logo" style="background-color: #fbc111">
    <img src="../../../assets/lbtrackerlogo.png" style="width: 250px;padding: 15px">
    <button class="btn btn-default" routerLink="create" style="position: absolute;top:25px;left: 80%">Create Agency</button>
</div>
```

**create.component.html**

```
<h1>Create Component</h1>
```

**create.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UUIDService } from '../../../services/uuid.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'create',
    templateUrl: 'create.component.html'
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log("In Create component");
    }
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './components/admin/create/create.component';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ['admin'] },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: CreateComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

[image: File Structure] [image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another child route inside your AdminComponent which will be a default route. Than copy your AdminComponent's logic, styles and view into the created child route and it should work fine.

When you define a child route it's working kind-of like in HTML. You have your parent that has some content and then by adding the child you're not deleting the parent's content - you're just adding the child's content to it's parent.

So you're routes should look like:

```
Admin - /admin - redirects to AdminDefaultController by default
    AdminDefaultController - /admin/dashborad 
    AdminCreateController - /admin/create
```

Comment: Im glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Your `<router-outlet>` should be inside your `app.component.html` file to avoid that kind of behavior.

You might be forgetting to add `CreateComponent` to your `app.module.ts`. Make sure you have CreateComponent inside your module declarations.

Comment: Yes, I have both of them. **app.component.html** <div class="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div> and app.module.ts here: [link](https://justpaste.it/154785452358)